# Why a unnamed <div> is added to a specific region?

Tags: theming, 8

I have 2 blocks in a region (*headline*). Drupal 8 seems to add these 2 blocks into an unnamed div and thus their `display:flex` CSS layout is cancelled. (You can't scatter 2 container items if these are wrapped into one `<div>`.)

I might need to note that the template markup also doesn't contain such HTML element.

The markup for the region is the following one.

```html
<div id="headline">
<div class="container">
{% if page.headline %}
     {{ page.headline }}
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS code I used is the following.

```css
#headline . container {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  #headline .container {
    display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; align-content: flex-start; flex: 1; margin: 0 auto
  }
}
```

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout **Twig Debug** to see where the template is coming from.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/locating-template-files-with-debugging

https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/twig/twig-debug.html

It will wrap the template with HTML comments telling you where to find it relative to the website root.

Some of the `<div>` tags provide containers for applying attributes to for things like **contextual links** and **quick edit**, so be cognizant of that when removing them when they have `{{ attributes }}` printed in them. Those CSS class attributes and data attributes are only are filled when those modules are enabled.

Answer (score 4):

It could be coming from region.html.twig:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21region.html.twig/8.2.x

Answer (score -2):

```
{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

→

```
{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes != '' }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```